# AWS choices for single microservice (spring boot) for Angular 7 client

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I'm relatively new to AWS and wanted suggestions about the best options for my needs. I have a single spring boot API that is to be accessible only to my angular 7 client. The client will go in an S3 bucket. I need suggestions for how to host the API (it needs a MySQL autogenerated db).

So far I have seen ECS vs Elastic Beanstalk vs. Amplify. Can someone experienced suggest me an option that won't be overkill for this small project? The API could be called frequently depending on traffic to the client.

If you have suggestions from Azure or Google Cloud Platform those would be welcome too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AWS provides the EC2 service where you can create an instance (virtual machine) and install/deploy manually your application and all the required software. For personal or very small projects this can be an option, but you should consider that your backend will not be able to scale to more instances automatically (or by configuration), you will have to take care of the configuration and backups of your database, etc.

For production-grade applications there are a lot of advantages of separating your application components, using a specific service for each component.

Given your application stack, I would recommend considering this approach:

- Create a relational DB with AWS RDS
- Deploy your Spring backend to AWS Beanstalk
- Deploy your Angular frontend to AWS S3 (it can be served as static content)
- Create a CloudFront distribution with two origins, to route the requests that must be delivered to backend (usually using a URL convention like /api/*) and frontend (*)

Comment: I'm implementing a similar situation but unable to get the front end talk to the backend.
for eg: 1. To which address would the HTTPclient in angular app call to invoke the backend running in ELB?
2. In my backend, what do I do to accept calls from angular app @Crossorgin("what goes here") ?

Comment: If you are following a similar approach (with AWS CloudFront), in your Angular app you can make calls to relative URLs ("/api/my-service"), no need to specify a host. Then in CloudFront you put a rule that every request with a specific URL pattern (like /api/*) is sent to your backend. So no need to Crossorgin configuration (the domain where the browsers downloads the front code and where you make backend calls is the same).